# Dynamic generated html controls cannot send exact row value

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a problem in getting the exact row value from the dyanamically generated html table with controls. Based on this value I will be calling a function in which I will updated the user input to DB. I need to get the row value in drop down change event

```html
<table id='TFtable'>

<tr> <td align='left'> <input type="button" value="Add More Task" onClick="addRow('TFtable')" name="Add Task"></td> </tr>

</table>

<script>
var rowcount;
function addRow(tableID)
{
rowcount =document.getElementById(tableID).rows.length;
rowcount=rowcount-2;
rowcount=rowcount+1;
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var row = table.insertRow(-1);

label = row.insertCell(0);
var element6 = document.createElement("Label");
element6.id="sno"+rowcount;
element6.name="sno"+rowcount;
label.innerHTML=rowcount;
label.appendChild(element6);



var cel1l = row.insertCell(1);
var element1 = document.createElement("select");
element1.id="Category"+rowcount;
element1.name="Category"+rowcount;
element1.onchange =function(){getrowcount(rowcount);};
element1.className="selectBox";

var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value ="Automation-Work";
option1.text ="Automation-Work";
element1.appendChild(option1);

var option1a = document.createElement("option");
option1a.value ="Document-Work";
option1a.text ="Document-Work";
element1.appendChild(option1a);

cel1l.appendChild(element1);


}

function getrowcount(rowvalue)
{
alert (rowvalue);
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is this calculation ? -> `rowcount =document.getElementById(tableID).rows.length;
rowcount=rowcount-2;
rowcount=rowcount+1;`

Comment: its some test code. Sorry!!!

Comment: you can consider like this rowcount =document.getElementById(tableID).rows.length;
rowcount=rowcount+1;

Comment: if I could send every row's label.innerHTML then its fine for me

Comment: Hello, please Any one help me with the answer  ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will log the current rowIndex. for that we will find the parent `tr` element using `parentNode` property, inside select's change function.

```js
var selectArr = document.querySelectorAll('select')
selectArr.forEach(function(item){
item.addEventListener("change",function(e){
   console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)
},false);
})
```

```css
table, td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><select>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>45</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td><select>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>45</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td><select>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>45</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you code not working. Its showing some error in Run Code Snippet

Comment: what error? I am not seeing any. We have binded change event. so you have to change the value..like 123 to 45 and not 123 to 123